# App freezes on including a function( ) that writes file from buffer

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android development and I am stuck. Here, I am recording voice using `audiorecorder` instead of `mediarecorder` to use noise cancellation feature and I am writing a PCM file from the buffer to an output file and when I include the function for writing the file from the buffer the app just don't respond. it records and saves the file but freezes.
can somebody tell me what's wrong?

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    // Write the output audio in byte
    bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
      RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
      RECORDER_CHANNELS,
      RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING
    );

    String filePath = "/sdcard/voice8K16bitmono.wav";
    short sData[] = new short[bufferSizeInBytese/2];

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        ar.read(sData, 0, bufferSizeInBytese/2);
        Log.d("eray","Short wirting to file" + sData.toString());
        try {
            // // writes the data to file from buffer
            // // stores the voice buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private byte[] short2byte(short[] sData) {
    int shortArrsize = sData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[shortArrsize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < shortArrsize; i++) {
       bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (sData[i] & 0x00FF);
       bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (sData[i] >> 8);
       sData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are doing file writing operation in main thread (UI thread), that's why app freezes. Kindly do your file operation in another thread Eg. ***AsyncTask***.

Keep in mind that "you do not do the operations which takes more than 5seconds & freezes app".

Here, just sharing the overview of concept to be added:

Add this innerclass inside your activity file.

```
static class FileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
     
        // do your file writing stuff here....
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        
        // update UI - if the file writig is success / failed 
    }
}
```

call this async task in your activity file when file need to be written:

```
 new FileAsyncTask().execute(...);
```

Comment: thank you for the idea but i am not able to get the variable value to the thread class from the main class .I want to get the filepath from main class but in log it shows null.

Comment: Please pass filepath using new FileAsyncTask().execute(filepath);.   And get that filepath in doInBackground of asynctask.

Comment: If you are new to asynctask, pls go through it.

Comment: Also a newbie here, but: why is your `sData[]` of size `bufferSizeInBytes/2` if your AudioRecord has buffer size `bufferSizeInBytes`? I have seen also defining the AudioRecord with size `2*bufferSizeInBytes`. Confused...